# Laravel: Vue is not defined for plugin

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create a plugin for global functions in `Laravel 8.4 / VueJs 2`. I have tried creating a file `plugin.js` in the same folder as `app.js`

*plugin.js*

```
const Plugin = {

  install(Vue, options) {

    Vue.prototype.toTitleCase = (str) => {
        return str.split(' ')
            .map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substring(1).toLowerCase())
            .join(' ');
    }

  },
}

Vue.use(Plugin)
```

*app.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
require('./plugin.js');
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at Object../resources/js/plugin.js
```

I have tried doing the import int the plugin file. However this just leads to more errors.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize vue on window using window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Your app.js should look like

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
import Vue from 'vue';
require('./plugin.js');
```